# Do Bayesian estimators under square error loss have an invariance property?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, estimators, conjugate-prior

I feel like this is something we went over in class but it's not coming to me for some reason.  I need to find the Bayesian estimator for $\tau(\theta)=e^{-\theta}$ under square error loss.  I already found the Bayesian estimator for $\theta$ (idk if you'll need the context but the prior was Gamma($\alpha,\beta$) and the parameter of interest was that of iid Poisson variables). I don't know if I can just take the expectation of $e^{-\theta}$ and call it a day or what I need to do.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No invariance property. Bayes estimator of $\theta$ under squared error loss is $E[\theta\mid X]$. Similarly Bayes estimator of $\tau(\theta)$ under squared error loss is $E[\tau(\theta)\mid X]$.

Comment: If $\exp\{-\theta\}$ is estimated under the squared error loss, the Bayes estimator is the posterior expectation. It is unclear what you mean by invariance in this context.

Comment: Thank you, guys!  That answers my question

Comment: Then can you please write an answer to the Q yourself (that is, in the answer box) so this do not linger on as unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people in the comments, I can conclude that Bayesian estimators under square error loss do not have an invariance property, and the Bayes estimator of $\tau(\theta)$ under square error loss is $E(\tau(\theta)|X)$.